# Using dataframes with pytest

Tags: python, pandas, pytest

I am trying to design a test with pytest.

This involves some operation on some data that gives as a result a pandas dataframe.

I would like to `assert` that all elements of the dataframe are:

- zero
- below a small threshold

EDIT: Also I would like to `assert` only elements from certain columns to be below a threshold

How can I use pandas dataframes together with pytest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) with `axis=None` for test if all values are Trues, here if all values are `0` or less like threshold, for numeric columns use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) with `np.number`:

```
#test only numeric columns
df1 = df.select_dtypes(np.number) 
th = 0.01
assert (df1.eq(0) | df1.lt(th)).all(axis=None)
```

Comment: I am getting the error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'`. This is not because of the headers, is it?

Comment: @KansaiRobot - What is `print (df.dtypes)` ? Seems some columns are non numeric

Comment: my mistake. I forgot some str values in the df. Now I am trying to see how can I exclude those. Any idea on how to evaluate only certain columns?